# Is it "Ollivanders" or "Ollivander's"?

Tags: harry-potter, names

#### What is the correct way to refer to the wand shop owned by Mr. Ollivander?

- I've seen plenty of people say

  > Ollivander's Wand Shop

  as in, "The Wand Shop belonging to Mr. Ollivander".
- But I've also seen it as

  > Ollivanders

  with no apostrophe.<sup>*</sup>

---

<sup>*</sup> If it is "Ollivanders" with no apostrophe, then please explain to me why it has no apostrophe. The shop belongs to him, so I would think you'd need the apostrophe to make it possessive, etc.

Comment: Might I ask the purpose of the question? Giving proof of something or? :) JC

Comment: @MacCooper I've had this question for a while. While researching my question, I found an answer, but rather than keep it to myself I wanted to share information. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The sign Mr. Ollivander uses for his shop *doesn't* use an apostrophe. It simply reads

> Ollivanders - Makers of Fine Wands since 382 B.C.

[image: sign reads: Ollivanders - Makers of Fine Wands since 382 B.C.]

The [wiki](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Ollivanders) sheds some light on why the sign doesn't use an apostrophe:

> Ollivanders in South Side, Diagon Alley, London, **is owned by the Ollivander family** and run by an older family member Garrick Ollivander, known only as Mr. Ollivander. Mr. Ollivander has been *serving as the family shopkeeper* at least since the 1930s, and remembers every wand he's ever sold. The **Ollivander family** are widely acknowledged to be the best wandmakers in Britain, and rank among the finest wandmakers in Europe. **Wandmaking has been the family business** since 382 B.C. Although there are other wandmakers in Britain

The entire Ollivander family owns the shop, as **it's a family business**. So the sign says "Ollivanders" as in the plural of Ollivander - multiple Ollivanders own the shop and likely have served as shopkeeper, not *just* Mr. Garrick Ollivander.

That said, it is probably still acceptable to say "Ollivander's Wand Shop" as the shop does belong to him (and his family). It's just not the *official* name for the shop.

For example, you could say:

- > "I got my wand from Ollivanders"

  Here you're using the shop's name, so it makes sense.
- > "I got my wand from Ollivander's Wand Shop"

  Here you're not using the shop's *official* name, but it still makes sense because you're describing the shop in a complete sentence.

You probably ***shouldn't*** say/write it as:

- > "I got my wand from Ollivander's"

  That doesn't make a lot of sense because it isn't a complete sentence.

Answer (score 3):

### It is "Ollivanders"

The books (specifically the first) use the form without the apostrophe.

> "Don' mention it," said Hagrid gruffly. "Don' expect you've had a
> lotta presents from them Dursleys. Just Ollivanders left now - only
> place fer wands, Ollivanders, and yeh gotta have the best wand."
>
> —*Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone*

Indeed, this is what it says on the sign, not only in the films, but in book canon:

> The last shop was narrow and shabby. Peeling gold letters over the
> door read Ollivanders: Makers of Fine Wands since 382 B.C. A single
> wand lay on a faded purple cushion in the dusty window.
>
> —*Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone*

Why is this? It does not have to do with grammatical correctness. If the point were to reference that the shop was owned by Garrick Ollivander, then the form would be "Ollivander's." If instead the shop were jointly owned by the Ollivander family, an appropriate form would be "Ollivanders'." Rather, this seems merely to be misuse, or variant use, of the apostrophe, which is exceedingly common in shop names. Here is an analogous example.

[image]